# Django template if conditional failure

Tags: django, templates, conditional-statements

I can't work out why the code between the if conditional isn't showing. Without the conditional the code shows fine.

```
{% if current_user_is_not_crew %}
<p>
<form action="/commit/" method="post" id="event-commit">
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="{{ event.id }}">
<input type="submit" value="Commit to this event">
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
</p>
{% endif %}
```

I know that the variable current_user_is_not_crew is true because I have debugged with:

```
Assert False, locals()
```

in the view, which has shown me it. views.py looks like this:

```
@login_required
def event(request, event_id):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    crew = event.userprofile_set.all()
    current_user = request.user.get_profile()
    if current_user in crew:
         current_user_is_not_crew = False
    else:
         current_user_is_not_crew = True
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context['event'] = event
    context['crew'] = crew
    context['current_user'] = current_user_is_not_crew
    return render_to_response('event.html', context)
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

The variable you've passed to the template is `current_user`, not `current_user_is_not_crew`.

Your template if block should be referencing `current_user`.

Comment: Thanks. Just clocked that myself. So basic!